# Alternate for TelecomManager.endCall()

Tags: android, call, telecom-manager

I have created a test internal application to reject the **native phone calls**.
I am using below code to `reject` the calls.

`TelecomManager tm = (TelecomManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
tm.endCall();`

But the thing is; `endCall` method is `Deprecated`.
Is there any alternative for this method?

Comment: Use the Call Screening APIs introduced in Android 9.0 (API level 28) - specifically the callScreeningService which allows you to create a foreground service that can screen and reject incoming calls programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

From the [aosp documentation](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/telecomm/java/android/telecom/TelecomManager.java;l=1926;drc=e274a5ef062925c35b042726f9dff8c0fd6cabd6) :

> ```java
> * @deprecated Companion apps for wearable devices should use the {@link InCallService} API
> * instead.  Apps performing call screening should use the {@link CallScreeningService} API
> * instead.
> ```

To end the call, your application needs to manage the calls by implementing the [InCallService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService). Your custom service will then have the capabilities to [get ongoing calls](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService#getCalls()) and [disconnect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call#disconnect()) them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InCallService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService)

Example:

1. Create your own MyInCallService , which is expanded with the help of the InCallService

   ```
   import android.telecom.Call;
   import android.telecom.CallScreeningService;
   import android.telecom.InCallService;
   import android.telecom.TelecomManager;

   public class MyInCallService extends InCallService {

   @Override
   public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
       // Handle incoming call.
       // To disconnect the call, you can use the endCall method.
       call.disconnect();
   }
   }
   ```
2. Add your service to the Manifest

   ```
    <service android:name=".MyInCallService"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_IN_CALL_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.InCallService" />
       </intent-filter>
    </service>
   ```

You can also use [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have add `feature-permission` in your `manifest.xml` file

you should use the Telecom framework if your app targets Android 10 (API level 29) and above. The `TelecomManager.endCall()` method is part of this framework.
Java:

```
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) 
{
TelecomManager telecomManager = getSystemService(TelecomManager.class);
if (telecomManager != null) {
    telecomManager.endCall();
}
}
```